# Is this a correct way to implement a basic FSM in Lua for my FSM Diagram?

Tags: lua, state-machine

Hello Stack Overflow community! Sooo I'm trying to implement a basic FSM for AI in my Roblox game based on this FSM diagram I made. I will show the modules after the diagram and an example on how I'm using it in my NPC Module. I've looked at a lot of FSM implementations in other languages which look easier because I'm fairly new with Lua. Does this look like a decent start to a FSM implementation? If not what could I improve on and what functions are most used in FSM's? I'm trying to grasp my head around the FSM model since I will be working on games with AI and do not want insane amounts of if,else,booleans  etc... Thank you to anyone that can give me more insight on how I can learn this subject more!

---

### Diagram

[image: AI FSM Diagram]

### State Module:

```
local State = {}
State.__index = State

function State:New()
    local newState = {
            Init = function() print("Init ran") end,
            Update = function() print("Updating") end,
            Enter = function() print("Entering") end,
            Exit = function() print("Exiting") end,
    }
    setmetatable(newState, self)

    print("Created new state")
    return newState
end

return State
```

### StateMachine Module:

```
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local State = require(ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("State"))

local StateMachine = {}
StateMachine.__index = StateMachine

function StateMachine:Create()
    local machine = {}
    machine.initState = State:New()
    machine.currentState = machine.initState
    machine.currentState.Init()

    setmetatable(machine, self)
    return machine
end

function StateMachine:Update()
    if self.currentState ~= nil then
        self.currentState:Update()
    end
end

function StateMachine:SetState(state)
    assert(state ~= nil, "Cannot set a nil state.")
    self.currentState:Exit()
    self.currentState = state
    self.currentState.Init()
    self.currentState.Enter()
end

return StateMachine
```

Here's the way I'm using my version of a FSM.

Example:

```
newZombie.stateMachine = StateMachine:Create()

newZombie.idleState = State:New()
newZombie.idleState.Init = function()
    print("idle state init")
end
newZombie.idleState.Enter = function()
    print("idle state enter!")
end
newZombie.idleState.Update = function()
    print("idle state updating!")
    if not newZombie.target then
        print("Getting target")
    newZombie.target = newZombie:GetNearestTarget()
    end

    if newZombie.zombieTarget then
        print("Found target")             
        newZombie.stateMachine:SetState(newZombie.chaseState)
    end
end

newZombie.chaseState = State:New()
newZombie.chaseState.Init = function()
    print("chaseState init")
end
newZombie.chaseState.Enter = function()
    print("chaseState enter")
end
newZombie.chaseState.Update = function()
    print("chaseState updating!")
    if newZombie.target then
        local direction = (newZombie.target.Position - newZombie.rootPart.Position).Unit * 0.5
        local distanceToTarget = (newZombie.target.Position - newZombie.rootPart.Position).magnitude
        local MAX_ATTACK_RADIUS = 4
        local ray = Ray.new(newZombie.rootPart.Position, (newZombie.target.Position - newZombie.rootPart.Position).Unit * 500)
        local ignoreList = {}
        for i, v in pairs(ZombiesServerFolder:GetChildren()) do
            table.insert(ignoreList, v)
        end
        local hit, position, normal = Workspace:FindPartOnRayWithIgnoreList(ray, ignoreList)

        if not hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
            print("Walk Path")
        end

        if distanceToTarget >= MAX_ATTACK_RADIUS then
            newZombie.rootPart.CFrame = newZombie.rootPart.CFrame + direction
        else
            newZombie.stateMachine:SetState(newZombie.attackState)
        end
    else
            newZombie.stateMachine:SetState(newZombie.idleState)
        end
end

newZombie.attackState = State:New()
newZombie.attackState.Init = function()
    print("attackState init")
end
newZombie.attackState.Enter = function()
    print("attackState enter")
end
newZombie.attackState.Update = function()
    print("attackState updating!")
    if newZombie.target then
        local distanceToTarget = (newZombie.target.Position - newZombie.rootPart.Position).magnitude
        local MAX_ATTACK_RADIUS = 4

        if distanceToTarget >= MAX_ATTACK_RADIUS then     
            newZombie.stateMachine:SetState(newZombie.chaseState)
        end
    end
end
----------------------------------------------------
----               STARTING STATE               ----
----------------------------------------------------
newZombie.stateMachine:SetState(newZombie.idleState)
----------------------------------------------------
```

Also in the NPC update function I'm updating the state machines current state update function.

```
if self.stateMachine then
    self.stateMachine:Update()
end
```

Comment: For code review requests [CodeReview@stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) seems waaaay more suitable place.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/219120/finite-state-machine-for-chasing-and-attacking-a-target